# What the difference between find_by_product_id(params[:id]) vs find_by(params[:product_id])

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

Now I have three models: Product, Cart, CartItem. Here's the related methods and associations:

**cart.rb**

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :cart_items
   has_many :products, :through => :cart_items, :source => :product
```

**cart_item.rb** (it has 2 related integer columns, `:product_id` & `:cart_id`)

```
class CartItem < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :cart
   belongs_to :product
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :current_cart

  def current_cart
      @current_cart ||= find_cart
  end

  private

  def find_cart
      cart = Cart.find_by(id: session[:cart_id])
      if cart.blank?
         cart = Cart.create
      end
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      return cart
  end
end
```

---

In **carts_controller.rb** I defined a method to delete specific cart_item in carts#index page:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy_one
      @cart_item = current_cart.cart_items.find_by_product_id(params[:id])
      @product = @cart_item.product
      @cart_item.destroy
  redirect_to :back
```

---

In the first line of **destroy_one** method, I can use `find_by_product_id(params[:id])` to get the right cart_item

Then I tried `find_by(product_id: params[:id])` , it works too.

But if I use `find_by(params[:product_id])`,something went wrong. When I click delete button, it won't raise an exception, but it will delete **another cart_item.** It seems rails randomly picked a cart_item and delete it.

---

Obviously, `find_by(params[:product_id])` worked incorrectly here.

**My question is:**

In this case, I confused with how rails find the right object step by step ? In one Cart, there's many cart_items and products, its reasonable to locate a cart_item by using `:product_id`. But what's the difference between :

`find_by_product_id(params[:id])`  vs  `find_by(params[:product_id])`

Respectively, how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `find_by(params[:product_id])` wrong. You have to pass the key you want to search for explicitly like so:

```
find_by(product_id: params[:product_id])

User.find_by(id: 1)
-> User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Respectively you can use it as you stated already:

```
find_by_product_id(params[:product_id])

User.find_by_id(1)
-> User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

As you can see, both approaches generate the very same SQL query.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, after reading the Rails Guide and doing several experiments, now I can understand what you said. The problem was I misunderstood the way rails to retrieve data.